# Combining anchor and alias in one line in triggers parserError: 'Expected <block end>, but found '<alias>'

Tags: yaml, anchor, alias

I am trying to combine anchors and aliases in order to reuse values into several containers, under different names.

I tried the following code:

```
FWL_GV_NANSEN: &fwl_gv_nansen
  dtype: float
  value: 2715.0

FWL_GV_E3_2: &fwl_gv_e32 *fwl_gv_nansen
```

the goal is simply to have another variable FWL_GV_E3_2 containing the same information than FWL_GV_NANSEN that I could refer to later on.

Just the same than defining in Python (or other):

```
a = 5.0
b = a
c = b
```

But this triggers the following error message:

> yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
>     in "fwl_2.yml", line 7, column 3
>   expected < block end >, but found '< alias >'

Is there no way to assign the content of aliases to variable used to defined a new anchor (propagating the initial values through different variables?

PS: maybe YAML is not the best language for this since it would be trivial using python's variables for example but I have to use YAML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The YAML node properties (i.e. tags and anchors) can only occur on "real" nodes: collections (block or flow) or scalars.

You can see from the production rules that `c-ns-properties` can be used only there, but section for aliases also [states explicitly](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2786196):

> Note that an alias node must not specify any properties [...]

---

What *is* possible if your YAML parser gives you access to the original anchor/aliases, or some anchor-to-node/object mapping (such as my `ruamel.yaml` package for Python when used for round-tripping), is to use a tagged scalar:

```
FWL_GV_NANSEN: &fwl_gv_nansen
  dtype: float
  value: 2715.0

FWL_GV_E3_2: &fwl_gv_e32 !ref fwl_gv_nansen
```

with the constructor of the `!ref` object resolving the scalar `fwl_gv_nansen`, with some *application* specific code. Normally the anchor and alias events are resolved by the composer loader step *before* composing (and if so that information is no longer available).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer :) So basically, it's just not possible to do what I am trying to do with YAML since you cannot assign anchor to pointers like alias, they have to be directly linked to the "hard" content ?

Comment: Yes, they have to be to "hard" content. What you want to do is more powerful than needed for dumping data structures that have objects occurring in multiple places (recursively or not). I updated the answer with a potential use of tags, but that would need some hooking into the YAML loader from the application level and is not trivial.